# Process.Start() not Executing my Command after the First Time

Tags: c#, process, cmd, nsis

I have the following code that launches cmd.exe then execute the compilation of an NSIS script.

```
...
Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo()
{
    FileName = "cmd.exe",
    WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
};
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
if (!process.Start())
    throw new Exception("NSIS failed to start, find out why");

process.StandardInput.WriteLine(String.Format("\"{0}\" {1}", nsisExePath, packagePath));
process.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
//process.WaitForExit();
```

This works perfectly the first time I execute the code. However, all subsequent attempts to run this process in the same session fail. I have to restart my application to get it to work again. I have commented out the `WaitForExit()` method as this seems to cause the process to hang - the cmd.exe process never seems to get to the `exit` command.

*How can I get the NSIS process to properly exit, or how can I get this to work multiple times in a single session, what am I missing?*

The explicit command I am using to compile the NSIS script is "C:\Program Files (x86)\NSIS\makensis.exe ".

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You redirected StandardOutput but you never actually read from it, perhaps that is the problem? Also, why are you launching cmd.exe and not launching `nsisExePath` directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

makensis.exe is a console program, you gain nothing by using cmd.exe as a middleman to call makensis.exe. Quite the opposite, by bringing cmd.exe into the mix you are exposed to its `&`/`&&`/`||` operators and strange quote handling.

I would recommend that you just start makensis.exe directly.

If you for some reason you think you have to use cmd.exe then the commandline should be something like `cmd.exe /C if 1==1 "c:\path\otherapp.exe" "c:\inputfile.ext"`

- `/C` instructs cmd.exe to execute the command and then exit
- `if 1==1` is a hack to reduce the strange quote handling

Comment: Thanks for this Anders, most appreciated. I had no idea you needed to work around a "qoute handling" bug. I don't want to call makensis.exe directly as this will cause a UAC prompt that I then have to click or handle some other way...

Comment: @Killercam: makensis.exe should not require elevation, have you changed something on its compatibility tab in Windows?

Comment: No, I haven't. Or at least not that I am aware of. Of course intitally I dd exactly that; fireup makensis.exe directly and then I get a UAC warning... I will look into the compatibility avenue now... Thanks very much.

Comment: Thanks, not sure what was happening before, but I have changed to use NSIS directly and all is fine...